# Server/Service Discovery in Windows environment?

Tags: windows, active-directory

[UDDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration) is for locating services on the Internet. Is there anything similar for locating services in a corporate or enterprise environment? For example I might want my program to be able to find a central reporting or policy server without configuration. Is this something I can do with Active Directory? Or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use DNS; Microsoft uses it itself in Windows. For example, _ldap._tcp. will provide you with all the LDAP servers (i.e. all domain controllers) in the domain. If the service is guaranteed to be provided only on a single host, use A records. If the service is replicated, use SRV records, explicitly choice of service to clients (indeed, _ldap._tcp and _kerberos._tcp are stored as SRV records).

For selected kinds of services, there is also AD/LDAP support. For example, COM/RPC servers can be located in AD through the rpc-server and related AD classes; the API is [RpcNS (RPC Naming Service)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677639(VS.85).aspx)

Winsock has a ["Registration and Resolution" (RnR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677640(VS.85).aspx) API, which uses the Service-Instance AD class.

Whether any of this is useful partially depends on whether you can establish a company policy for how services should be located. There are various technologies, many of them useful, and it's more important that there is a single choice (or few alternatives), than that the "best" technology gets used.